# Get max date from columns in Redshift using a dynamically changing list of columns and tables with Python?

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-redshift

I am have a list of timestamp columns that correspond to specific tables in Redshift. I want to be able to grab the most recent date of all the timestamp columns for a given table. I can't just write the column names out because the tables have different column names. I have a dataframe with the table name and columns that I need

```
table_name      column              data_type
  tbl1       sent_at          timestamp without timezone
  tbl1       message_received timestamp without timezone
  tbl1       scene_updated    timestamp without timezone
  tbl2       phone_updated    timestamp without timezone
  tbl2       col2_updated     timestamp without timezone
  tbl3       sent_at          timestamp without timezone
  tbl3       number_updated   timestamp without timezone
```

I want to check from each table, the most recent date of all the timestamp columns. I am trying to create a query that involves creating a string that uses 'max()' and then populates inside the parenthesis to use within the query. Like so:

```
for table in set(df.table_name):
   sub = df[df.table_name == table]
   cols = [x for x in sub.column.values.tolist()]
   str_max = 'max()' * len(cols)
   que = 'select' + str_max + 'from {}'.format(table)
   time_table = pd.read_sql_query(que, conn) 
   ....
```

Then, I would used pandas to get the max value of all the columns. However, I can't figure out how to insert the column name in between the '()' to get the max value when all the column names change. Maybe there is a way within Redshift to look at the max of all column values while using a data_type filter but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using another for loop and appending the column names to a string. Then, I joined the list into a single string so I could put it into a single query. After the query ran, I used max() to find the max value of all columns.

```
for table in set(df.table_name):
    sub = created_at_tables[created_at_tables.table_name ==  table]
    cols = [x for x in sub.column_name.values.tolist() if x != 'table_updated_at']
    col_str = []
    for i in cols: 
       col_str.append('max(' + i + ') as ' + i)
    col_str = ','.join(col_str)
    que = 'select {} from schema.{}'.format(col_str, table)
    new_table = pd.read_sql_query(que, rsm.dbengine)
    new_table.dropna(axis = 1, inplace = True)
    most_recent_date = new_table.max(axis=1).reset_index()[0][0]
```